# How to decode and read a chm file in java?

Tags: java, filereader, chm

I see many suggestions to use the `jchm jar` to do this. However I don't see any code which shows how to read the `chm file` using the `jchm jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `hh.exe -decompile [destination_folder] chmfile.chm` to decompile the `.chm` into its underlying `.htm` files. I am now writing java code to parse all these `.htm` to create a tree structure to store the complex structure of hyperlinks in the .chm file.

Comment: Please have a closer look at. the decompiled *.hhc file. Maybe this is timesaving for your coding. For some *.hhc Information see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823171/hhc-file-of-chm-to-html

Comment: My thought I forgot is saving time by parsing the HHC file.